# Does SECURE BOOT need to be disabled on the Nexus 5 before I can install UBPort's Ubuntu Phone Image?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, canonical, secure-boot

Does SECURE BOOT need to be disabled on the Nexus 5 before I can install UBPort's Ubuntu Phone image?

I thought I read something about Ubuntu/Canonical having a Secure Boot certificate, but I am not exactly sure what that means, and whether it extends to Ubuntu Touch devices (Or in this case, UBPorts).

Comment: UBPorts is not an official supported Ubuntu system so offtopic. "
 Ubuntu/Canonical having a Secure Boot certificate" EVEN if it would include Touch it would NOT include UBPorts. They would need their own certificate

Comment: @Rinzwind https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17163/ubports-is-this-project-carrying-on-the-task-of-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-new-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "No".

You do not need to disable secure boot in order to install Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 5.

Source: I just installed it, and it went fine.